# How to programatically disable options in ui-select angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have two `ui-select` in my view. I want to disable some values in second `ui-select` with respect to first. That means when I change values to first, some of the values in second that are related to selected item in first, would be disabled.

Comment: Provide a plnkr with all your relevant code then we can help. Hard to say something with nothing concrete.

Answer (score 0):

If this is database-driven, is there a field which relates the data so as to be able to dynamically check values (e.g., types > subtypes)? If so, you can use `ng-if=""` to selectively load select items.

You would need some sort of relationship between the values to be able to programmatically (dynamically) perform the task. Otherwise, you'd have to manually do it.

Comment: Both the ui's are having static values that is not from database.

Comment: I would add them to an object which has a key-value relationship in the form of 
{ select-1: [enabled option, enabled option, enabled option], select-2: [enabled option, enabled option, enabled option ] }...
And so on. You could put this into the controller or, alternatively and preferably, in a custom directive since you are manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: the only way I can do is, call a function on selecting an option in first `ui-select` and disable the related options in second in the function. is there a way to do it ?